# Is there a machine learning algorithm which successfully learns the parity function?

Tags: machine-learning

The [parity function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_function) is a function from a vector of n bits and outputs 1 if the sum is odd and 0 otherwise. This can be viewed as a classification task, where the n input are the features.

Is there any machine learning algorithm which would be able to learn this function? Clearly random decision forests would not succeed, since any strict subset of features has no predictive power. Also, I believe no neural network of a fixed depth would succeed, since computing the parity function is not in the complexity class [AC0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AC0).

Comment: For fixed *n*, wouldn't a two-layer perceptron with a sufficiently large hidden layer be enough?

Comment: Well, yes it would. If one has one node in the hidden layer for every combination 00011110101 of input bits it is trivially possible. The number of hidden nodes will then grow exponentially with n.

Comment: Usually you should use around 2*n hidden nodes in your MLP with one hidden layer and it should work. Standard backpropagation is an outdated optimization algorithm for ANNs. I would suggest Levenberg-Marquardt, Conjugate Gradient, Quickprop or RProp instead.

Comment: alfa: right, but in this case I don't think polynomially many hidden layer nodes will work.

Answer (score 4):

Polynomial SVMs can do this.
Encode zeros as 1 and ones as -1.
For n variables (bits), you need a polynomial kernel of degree n.
When the kernel is computed, it also implicitly computes the value x1 * x2 * ... * xn (where xi is the i-th input variable). 
If the result is -1, you have an odd number of ones, otherwise you have an even number of ones.

If I'm not mistaken, Neural Networks should also be able to compute it. As far as I remember, Neural Networks with 2 hidden layers and sigmoid units are able to learn any arbitrary function.

Comment: Good point about the polynomial SVMs!

A NN with one hidden layer is trivially able to compute any Boolean function, but then the hidden layers would have to grow exponentially in n.

Comment: I guess I was under the false impression that NNs were somehow equivalent to Boolean circuits.

Answer (score 0):

What about Gaussian Process Classification? You can train your model by n-dimensional input vector and 1-dimensional parity bit output. Then for any test input you can ask for a prediction. You can check this online book.
http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters/
Chapter 3 addresses the classification problem.

Answer (score 0):

Neural Networks can represent and learn the parity function with a single hidden layer with the same number of neurons as inputs. The fact that the parity function is not in AC0 is a fact about circuits of boolean gates, but multi-layer perceptrons (as commonly used) can have real-valued weights, which makes all the difference.

An example of an explicit solution would the following, assuming `n` inputs, `n` hidden units and a sign activation function (described for example in [1]):

- Set all weights in the first layer to 1. This means that the pre-activation before the addition of the bias is the same for all hidden units and equal to the number of 1s in the input
- Set the bias in the first hidden unit to -0.5, the threshold for the second hidden unit to -1.5, for the third hidden unit to -2.5 etc. This means that if there is no 1 in the input and the pre-activations before the addition of the bias are 0, the pre-activation after the addition of the bias is negative for all hidden units and the sign function will return a 0 for all hidden units. If there is a single 1 in the input, only the pre-activation of the first hidden unit will be positive and there will therefore be a single hidden unit that will send a 1 to the output. In general, if there are `k` 1s in the input, the first `k` hidden units will send a 1 to the output, the rest a zero.
- Set the weights that connect the hidden units to the output +1, -1, +1, -1 etc. This means if there is no 1 in the input, the output will be 0. If there is a single 1 in the input, the output will be +1. If there are two 1s in the input, the output will be again +1-1=0 and so on.

That solves the parity problem.

Your were asking, however, about machine learning algorithms that can *learn* this function. According to the section "Parity" in [2], the answer is that at least for small `n`, back-propagation on a single-layer neural network can learn the function and, in fact, it actually learns a network very similar to the one described above.

[1] Franco, Leonardo, and Sergio A. Cannas. "Generalization properties of modular networks: implementing the parity function." IEEE transactions on neural networks 12.6 (2001): 1306-1313.

[2] Rumelhart, David E., Geoffrey E. Hinton, and Ronald J. Williams. Learning internal representations by error propagation. No. ICS-8506. California Univ San Diego La Jolla Inst for Cognitive Science, 1985.