# Using machine learning (ANN) to classify odd numbers

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, keras, numbers, discrete-mathematics

Can you get improvement on this models prediction of odd numbers? The best I could get was 50% however big and deep my neural network is.

```
from tensorflow import keras

X=[]
Y=[]
n=100
for i in range (n):
    X+=[i]
    Y+=[(-1)**i]
    if Y[i]<0:
        Y[i]=0

model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(1, )),
    keras.layers.Dense(2, activation=tf.nn.softmax),
    keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
])

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer="adamax",metrics=['binary_accuracy'])
model.fit(X, Y, epochs=100,batch_size=10)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not such a trivial task, ask you might expect it to be. You can find one working model in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9484847/is-there-a-machine-learning-algorithm-which-successfully-learns-the-parity-funct) SO thread. Furthermore, this is still an active field of research (called parity problem). The accuracy of your network might increase if you do not give it an integer as the input, but the binary representation of the numbers. Otherwise, your network will (most likely) not be able to solve this task.

You can find more information about the problem of neural networks concerning arithmetical operations in [this](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/154/is-it-possible-to-train-the-neural-network-to-solve-math-equations) SE thread, too. Depending on how deeply you want to understand this problem, there are also a lot of papers from the past dealing with this problem (e.g. [this](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/657-optimal-depth-neural-networks-for-multiplication-and-related-problems.pdf) or [that](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0925231297000696)).

In general arithmetical operations are possible if you are supplying the network with a binary representation and not just the decimal version. You can even determine the exact number of neurons an ANN must have to perform specific task of this class.

Comment: Wow! I thought something was wrong with my method or code. The best prediction I could get the model to predict was at best no better than flipping a coin!

Answer (score 0):

To complete FlashTek's answer neural networks have problems with specific arithmetic operations, namely *multiplication, division and derived operations*, cf **https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/217703/can-deep-neural-network-approximate-multiplication-function-without-normalizatio** and [Can't approximate simple multiplication function in neural network with 1 hidden layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37520849/cant-approximate-simple-multiplication-function-in-neural-network-with-1-hidden)

This is because of the mathematical framework that neural nets are part of, they are a nonlinear generalization of *Generalized Linear Model (GLM)*  ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_linear_model , http://mikkyang.com/blog/neural-networks-and-generalized-linear-models/index.html ) and *Weighted* **Sum** *Model (WSM)* ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_sum_model ), note that in GLM and WSM no multiplication between tensors ( matrices, vectors ) is involved, only multiplication with a scalar weight. This is why neural nets can not  be applied to or are insufficient in solving mathematical problems that have a specific structure ( that involve multiplication, division , ... )